# Render Form ViewSet Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, forms, django-rest-framework, rendering

I would like to do the following:

With my model

```
class User(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   fk1 = models.ForeignKey(Group)
goes on
```

After this, I created my Serializer, which looks like:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserSerializer
        fields = (...)

    ...
```

Lastly, I create my ViewSet, which should look like this:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

but now, how would I be able to create a viewSet and, for example, generate a form with my class? My final idea is to be able to do something like:

```
def my_view(request):
   my_form = UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}(request))
   # from here either to be able to use .render().content
   # or, inside the template, render with {% render_form my_form %}
```

Is this possible? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're suggesting is possible, but it doesn't usually make sense. Django Rest  Framework is great for creating an API so that you can send and receive information to and from that api, maybe in JSON format.

Getting a form involves getting rendered HTML from the server. That's a better task for Django itself. You could use a [`CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) to do what you're trying to:

```
def UserCreateView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = "name_of_your_form.html"  # Or you could call the form 'user_create_form.html` and leave this line out.
    fields = [...]
```

Your form will then be available in your template, per the docs:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you suggest me a better way to do so? I am open to good practices.. I am just starting to learn it.. I need to keep serializers though

Answer (score 2):

As docs says:

> Serializers may be rendered as forms by using the render_form template tag, and including the serializer instance as context to the template.

Next example will probably work for you. But how @YPCrumble sayed DRF goal is easy and fast build an API, not rendering forms

```
class UserDetail(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'your_template.html'

    def get(self, request, pk):
        serializer = UserSerializer(profile)
        return Response({'serializer': serializer})

    def post(self, request, pk):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'serializer': serializer})
        serializer.save()
        return redirect('some_url_name')
```

template file:

```
{% load rest_framework %}
<html><body>

   <form action="{% url 'user_url' pk=user.pk %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% render_form serializer %}
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>

</body></html>
```

`[DRF Docs link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/#rendering-forms)